# angular uncaught (in promise) error loading chunk failed Microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, lazy-loading, angular-ngmodel

I am getting issue while using angular and Microsoft Edge browser, app is working fine in chrome & another browser but in Microsoft Edge, i am getting this[image]

Any Suggestions?.

Comment: Try to add this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in your `index.html` file.

Comment: Same error nothing changed